# How to compare two xml files in mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2012

I have 2 files of type :

```
@xmlAuthors1 XML =N'
       <Author name="John" surname="Clinton" />
       <Author name="Bill" surname="Skobov" />
       <Author name="John" surname="Lokwood" />;

@xmlAuthors2 XML =N'
       <Author name="Bill" surname="Skobov" />
       <Author name="John" surname="Clinton" />
       <Author name="John" surname="Lokwood" />;
```

how do find out that they are equal? compare each line of the file 1 with each line from of the file 2

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9013680/t-sql-how-can-i-compare-two-variables-of-type-xml-when-length-varcharmax

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example you can compare them like:

```
DECLARE @xmlAuthors1 XML = N'
               <Author name="John" surname="Clinton" />
               <Author name="Bill" surname="Skobov" />
               <Author name="John" surname="Lokwood" />',
        @xmlAuthors2 XML =N'
               <Author name="Bill" surname="Skobov" />
               <Author name="Johns" surname="Clinton" />
               <Author name="John" surname="Lokwood" />'


SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT  CAST(x1.t.query('.') as nvarchar(max)) as x1,
            CAST(x2.t.query('.') as nvarchar(max)) as x2
    FROM @xmlAuthors1.nodes('/*') as x1(t)
    FULL OUTER JOIN @xmlAuthors2.nodes('/*') as x2(t)
        ON CAST(x1.t.query('.') as nvarchar(max)) = CAST(x2.t.query('.') as nvarchar(max))
) as x
WHERE x1 is null or x2 is null
```

If there are equal there will be no output

Comment: Did you test this with data not equal?

Comment: Just looked a bit closer... Your idea is very close to mine, you cast the full element as string... But the `WHERE x1 != x2` does not handle the `NULL`s, which indicate the missing values from the `FULL OUTER JOIN`...

Comment: Yes, I have tested, Works fine if x1 has value and x2 is null or x1 is null and x2 with value.

Comment: or something I do not understand, but your example is not running, it is activated only when it is necessary to find an equal line. operation not equal not show anything when the line is different, or their number is different

Comment: Pretty strange, I'll re-check later. On a sample I provided it outputs two rows, if remove 's' from 'Johns' - no rows, this was yesterday when I checked.

Comment: I checked it example in Sql-Server 2012 and Sql-Server 2016. Result is the same, as I wrote above

Comment: The one come in my mind is to change WHERE statement. Please, check it.

Comment: @Alex indeed `x1 != x2` is not working... How I checked, I don't know. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what equal means to you. I would compare data as follows:

```
DECLARE @xmlAuthors1 XML =N'
       <Author name="John" surname="Clinton" />
       <Author name="Bill" surname="Skobov" />
       <Author name="John" surname="Lokwood" />
       <Author name="John" surname="Blurred" />';

DECLARE @xmlAuthors2 XML =N'
       <Author name="Bill" surname="Skobov" />
       <Author name="John" surname="Clinton" />
       <Author name="John" surname="Lokwood" />';

WITH Xml1 AS
(
    SELECT
        T.A.value('@name', 'varchar(20)') Name,
        T.A.value('@surname', 'varchar(20)') Surname
    FROM @xmlAuthors1.nodes('/Author') T(A)
), Xml2 AS
(
    SELECT
        T.A.value('@name', 'varchar(20)') Name,
        T.A.value('@surname', 'varchar(20)') Surname
    FROM @xmlAuthors2.nodes('/Author') T(A)
)
SELECT 'Unique in 1' [Description], * FROM (SELECT * FROM Xml1 EXCEPT SELECT * FROM Xml2) Q1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Unique in 2' [Description], * FROM (SELECT * FROM Xml2 EXCEPT SELECT * FROM Xml1) Q2
```

This particular example yields:

```
Description   Name    Surname
-----------   ----    -------
Unique in 1   John    Blurred
```

Answer (score 1):

This was my approach:

There is a nice trick with `.query(.data()).value()` to retrieve all inner text as space separated string. This makes it easy to compare on string level...

I changed your input to inlcude some more test cases:

```
DECLARE @xmlAuthors1 XML = N'
               <Author name="John" surname="Clinton" />
               <Author name="Bill" surname="Different" />
               <Author name="John" surname="Lokwood" />
               <Author name="Test" surname="it" />',
        @xmlAuthors2 XML =N'
               <Author name="Bill" surname="Skobov" />
               <Author name="John" surname="Clinton" />
               <Author name="John" surname="Lokwood" />
               <Author name="One" surname="More" />';

SELECT ISNULL(Author1,Author2) AS Author
      ,CASE WHEN Author1 IS NULL THEN 'Exists in 2' ELSE 'Exists in 1' END AS [Source]
FROM
(
    SELECT B.query('data(@*)').value('.','varchar(max)') AS Author1
    FROM @xmlAuthors1.nodes('/Author') AS A(B)
) AS tbl1
FULL OUTER JOIN
( 
    SELECT B.query('data(@*)').value('.','varchar(max)') As Author2
    FROM @xmlAuthors2.nodes('/Author') AS A(B)
)AS tbl2 ON Author1=Author2
WHERE Author1 IS NULL OR Author2 IS NULL
```

If you want to find those which are equal in both you might use this

```
SELECT B.query('data(@*)').value('.','varchar(max)') AS EqualAuthor
FROM @xmlAuthors1.nodes('/Author') AS A(B)
INTERSECT
SELECT B.query('data(@*)').value('.','varchar(max)') 
FROM @xmlAuthors2.nodes('/Author') AS A(B)
```